# Unrar in php by exec()

Tags: php, shell, ssh, compression, exec

I successfully unrar rar file in php with this simple command

```
$file="folder/$filename";
$string="unrar e '$file'";
exec($string);
```

The problem is that it does not unrar within the folder. It will copy files into the main directory, instead of the folder in which the rar file exists.

Comment: e should be same location as the rar file, but there are a few different rar implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "e"-switch means "Extract files to current directory" so remove that one and try again. Current means where you are running the command from and not where the file is.
You can also specify the path as the second parameter like this:
"unrar file [path]"

Answer (score 3):

Look into `unrar`'s options to see whether you can specify a target directory (most likely it's possible), or use [`chdir()`](http://php.net/chdir) to change the working directory.